# nodejs execute order using mysql

Tags: mysql, node.js

```
    conn = mysql.createConnection(options);
    conn.connect();
    var sql = 'select * from member';

    for(var i=0; i<3; i++){
      (function(){
        console.log(i);
        conn.query(sql, function(err,result){
          console.log('q');
        })
      })(i)
     }
      for (var i=0; i<2; i++){
        console.log(i)
      }
```

I'm using npm-mysql.
I expected the console would display '012qqq01', but actually I got '01201qqq'. 
I'm confused. Why is 'conn.querry' executed last? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Isn't the callback (or function) that you pass as second argument to `con.query` executed asynchronously? If it is executed in that way, that may explain your output...

Comment: Duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38945606/node-js-does-not-wait-for-the-mysql-server-sends-the-answer-and-continues-to-wo

Comment: If you're not familiar with asynchronous code you're going to have to get a handle on that before you write any more Node.js code. It's *extremely* dependent on this principle to the point of it being a driving philosophy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a function which logs `i` and then sends the queries to the database in a loop, and the logs through another loop. That function runs.

Either while that is going on, or sometime after it has finished, the results of the queries will be sent back from the database.

When the JS engine isn't busy running the first function, it will start checking to see if the event indicating a response from the database has arrived. Then it will call the callback function and log 'q'.

Comment: Thanks for a wise answer to a silly question very much. I wonder, if JS engine is busy, will JS engine call the callback? Or will it be just doing the busy work, not calling the callback, even if the response has arrived?

Comment: It will keep doing whatever it is doing. It won't stop in the middle of something to respond to an event.